# compute dynamic daily attendance using mysql

Tags: mysql

I am creating a web application in generating daily attendance per employee which they could clock-in/clock-out.
table 1 - list of employee

```
| userID | Fullname   | Employee ID |
| 1      | John Doe   | ABC-0001    |
| 2      | Jeffrey Doe| ABC-0002    |
```

table 2 - attendance

```
| attendanceID | userID | Date       | Time                | Remarks |
| 1            | 1      | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 07:00:00 | IN      |
| 2            | 2      | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 07:30:25 | IN      |
| 3            | 1      | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 17:01:25 | OUT     |
| 4            | 2      | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 18:05:00 | OUT     |
```

I tried this code to generate the attendance - horizontal view.

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      '(CASE WHEN Date = ',
      Date,
      ' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,SUM(CASE WHEN Remarks="IN" THEN TIME END),SUM(CASE WHEN Remarks="OUT" THEN TIME END)) END) AS ',
      CONCAT('"',Date,'"')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tblattendance;

SET @sql =
  CONCAT('SELECT a.Fullname,a.EmployeeID, ', @sql, ' FROM tblemployee a LEFT JOIN tblattendance b ON b.eID = a.eID GROUP BY a.userID');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

But I received some warning(s) like :

```
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '2023-03-10'
```

OR

```
| John Doe | ABC-0001 | NULL |
```

Hope you could help me to resolve this.

Here's the output that I wish to generate

```
| Fullname      | EmployeeID | 2023-01-01 |
| John Doe      | ABC-0001   | 9          |
| Jeffrey Doe   | ABC-0002   | 9          |
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: Add `SELECT @sql;` instead of PREPARE/EXECUTE and look at the query text correctness.

Comment: 'generate the attendance' on what basis (difference between in and next out?)? and what measure (hours,days,minutes), are we to assume that there are no overnight shifts worked?

Comment: Not a unique question try a bit of research for example https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109257/mysql-timeclock-count-hours-in-out-for-each-day-of-current-week is close.

Comment: @P.Salmon it will compute total hours based on the time, so its possible that there's a overnight shift

Comment: @P.Salmon how come that it is a not a unique question? It will generate horizontal results based on the date. see the desired output. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample data you have `Employee ID` and `userID`, but in your query you have `EmployeeID`, `eID` and no mention of `userID`.  You are missing the quotes for the `Date` value in your `GROUP_CONCAT`.

The current query would be illegal anyway, as you have expressions outside of aggregate functions which are not functionally dependant on the `GROUP BY` clause.

This will build, prepare and execute the query you were going for:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        'TIMESTAMPDIFF(
            HOUR,
            SUM(CASE WHEN `Remarks` = ''IN''  AND `Date` = ''', `Date`, ''' THEN `Time` END),
            SUM(CASE WHEN `Remarks` = ''OUT'' AND `Date` = ''', `Date`, ''' THEN `Time` END)
        ) AS ''', `Date`, ''''
    ) INTO @sql
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `Date` FROM `tblattendance`) t;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT e.Fullname, e.EmployeeID, ', @sql, ' FROM tblemployee e LEFT JOIN tblattendance a ON a.userID = e.userID GROUP BY e.userID');

SELECT @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0FflYcaJ).

Please note, this approach will create junk output when you are missing an `IN` or `OUT` entry, or when the `IN` is on one day and the `OUT` on the next day.